# yii2 convert users timezone to database timezone for saving

Tags: yii2, timezone

It's easy to convert a UTC (database) time into the users timezone using yii2's formatter (see below), however, how do you convert a users timezone back into the database timezone?

My config file is as follows:

```
....
'formatter' => [
   'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
   'defaultTimeZone'=>'UTC',// for saving values in the database            
   'timeZone'=>'America\New_York', // for displaying timezones
],....
```

To display the users local timezone, it's easy to just call:

```
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDatetime($model->date_created);
```

How do you convert it back so that when they submit a value, I can convert it back into UTC format?

Comment: You need to be more specific what you would like to save and how.

Comment: Guess you could just set `\Yii::$app->formatter->timeZone = 'UTC';` when you need to (assuming the input contains time zone information)... though, I don't think the formatter is really intended for this kind of use. You may want to look into using [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) instead, which you can initialize with the time data from the user along with a time zone, and then convert between time zones and format as you like, or just use a UNIX timestamp if that's what you store in your database.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Thernys, the user submits their local timezone, and it gets converted in the model as follows:

```
protected function convertToServerDate($date, $format = 'n/j/Y g:i A', 
  $userTimeZone = 'America/Los_Angeles', $serverTimeZone = 'UTC')
  {
    try {
      $dateTime = new DateTime ($date, new DateTimeZone($userTimeZone));
      $dateTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone($serverTimeZone));
      return $dateTime->format($format);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return '';
    }
  }
```

and then in my model validation rules do this:

```
public function rules(){
  return [
   .....
   [['datetimeattribute'],'filter','filter'=>function($value){
     return $this->convertToServerDate($value,'Y-m-d H:i:s',Yii::$app->formatter->timeZone,Yii::$app->formatter->defaultTimeZone)
   }]
 .....
];
```

Comment: It helped. Just suggestion, use date format as 'Y-m-d H:i:s T' because rules() function may execute mulitple times when both validation() and save() are called resulting in timezone conversion twice. So its better to specify timezone with date.